# Running a bitcoin node on regtest network fails

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I'm trying to run a bitcoin network on regtest with [this version of bitcoin node](https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node/) so I can test out [bitpay's insight-ui block explorer](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-ui).

Running on regtest I get this repeating error

```
Assertion failed: (psocket), function Shutdown, file zmq/zmqpublishnotifier.cpp, line 92.
[2017-05-19T00:42:44.515Z] warn: Bitcoin process unexpectedly exited with code: null
[2017-05-19T00:42:44.515Z] warn: Restarting bitcoin child process in 5000ms
[2017-05-19T00:42:49.516Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /Users/harshagoli/BTCT/bitcoin.conf
[2017-05-19T00:42:49.517Z] warn: Stopping existing spawned bitcoin process with pid: 12690
[2017-05-19T00:42:49.517Z] warn: Unclean bitcoin process shutdown, process not found with pid: 12690
[2017-05-19T00:42:49.517Z] info: Starting bitcoin process
```

Which eventually becomes

```
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.133Z] error: RPCError: Bitcoin JSON-RPC: Request Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8332
    at Bitcoin._wrapRPCError (/Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:449:13)
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:781:28
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/bitcoind-rpc/lib/index.js:116:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:269:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:458:9)
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.133Z] info: Beginning shutdown
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.133Z] info: Stopping insight-ui (not started)
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.134Z] info: Stopping insight-api (not started)
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.134Z] info: Stopping web (not started)
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.135Z] info: Stopping bitcoind
```

After which I have the reoccurring error

```
[2017-05-19T00:42:54.221Z] error: Error: Stopping while trying to spawn bitcoind.
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:905:25
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:676:51
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:264:21
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:652:25
    at /Users/harshagoli/mynode/node_modules/bitcore-node/lib/services/bitcoind.js:887:16
```

Thoughts on how I can get this up and running with a block to look at so I can use the block explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. What was happening is there were some other bitcoind processes that had zombied out and were listening on the port this process was trying to access. I ran this command to kill the other processes

```
killall -9 bitcoind
```

Also, to create more blocks on regtest (while in the your node directory) use this command.

```
./node_modules/bitcore-node/bin/bitcoin-0.12.1/bin/bitcoin-cli -datadir=/Users/harshagoli/mynode/data -regtest generate 150
```